# Understanding KML To Layer performance in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, kml, performance

I've got a very simple code using an ArcPy tool to convert KMLs to Layers in a directory:

```
import arcpy, os
from arcpy import env

arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\KML\Test"
outLocation = r"C:\KML\Test\Convert"

for kml in arcpy.ListFiles('*.KML'):
    print "Converting {0}".format(os.path.join(arcpy.env.workspace, kml))
    arcpy.KMLToLayer_conversion(kml, outLocation)
```

Each KML is no less than 20,000 KB and probably has 2000-3000 records per. On average, it is taking about 1.4 - 2 minutes for each KML to convert using the `arcpy.KMLToLayer_conversion()`.

Any thoughts on if this is a memory issue? Not sure why it appears to be running so slow.

Also of note, `import arcpy` causes the script to delay for about 5 seconds when it starts.

This code is run outside of ArcMap through IDLE.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  How many KML files are you converting?  How long does it take to convert just one, e.g. `arcpy.KMLToLayer_conversion(r"c:\temp\mykml.kml", r"c:\output")`

Comment: ArcPy is a very large library so I think that 5 second delay is to be expected when it is first imported. Where are you running your code?

Comment: @Midavalo The number of KMLs will vary, so that detail needs to be arbitrary; we use either 1, 30 or 365 files. I put in the post, it takes about 1.4-2 minutes per file that are generally 20K KB (20MB) in size each.

Comment: @PolyGeo Code is run outside of ArcMap through the Python IDLE. All of our scripts are written as standalone for integration into a larger tool or in-case one person errors another can use the segmented piece against their data without re-running the entire tool.

Comment: @pstatix You mentioned you thought it was a memory issue.  Often this is evidenced in the tools slowing down the more files it processes, so I asked how long it takes to run once just using a single command (outside of your script).  If it is consistent, then it may just be the speed of the tool rather than any speed issue.

Comment: @pstatix please [edit] your question to include any new information/clarification in response to comments.

Comment: @Midavalo That is the consistent speed for each individual file. Because the remainder of the code (not shown here and not relevant) runs very fast, I assumed memory was the issue at this bottleneck.

Comment: If it is consistent for each issuance of that geoprocessing tool then it suggests that you need to look at the performance of that tool with your data rather than at ArcPy.

Comment: Unfamiliar with how to do that. Point me in the right direction?

Comment: Choose any one of your KML files, convert it using the tool dialog instead of from a Python script, and then include the output displayed in the Results window as part of your question.  From there we will probably ask for more clarifications about the data to see whether we think the processing time seems reasonable.  How much RAM are you using?  What version of ArcGIS Desktop are you using?

Comment: Unfortunately you are not authorized to see the KML data. So I cannot do that. So I can redact and hopefully provide something useful. RAM I am unsure about (GFE) and ArcMap 10.2.

Comment: This has *nothing* to do with ArcPy performance  or memory -- caching a massive XML document simply takes a significant effort.

Comment: Note that I am not asking to see the data itself, only the report on what went in and what came out.

Comment: I consider a 20,000 KB kml to be quite large and would expect to see the processing times you are experiencing.  Most kmls I use are less than 1,000 KB and take ~10-20sec to convert.  10 * 20 = 200 seconds = 3min, so you're machine is processing faster than mine.

Comment: @PolyGeo The name of the files appears in the report and the names are of a sensitive nature for reasons I cannot specify here. Beyond that, they also reside on a system that does not connect to the "internet" as you know it. If I can develop a way to show the reports I will.

Comment: Honestly, all you have to do is to copy and rename one to C:/temp/test.kml and see how long it takes to process.

Comment: @PolyGeo Data resides on a different network, different terminals, different security. No way to get the report without handjamming.

Comment: Why not just create a Fishnet of the same size, convert it to a kml, and see how long it takes to convert back?

Answer (score 2):

I consider a 20,000 KB kml to be quite large and would expect to see the processing times you are experiencing.

Most kmls I use are less than 1,000 KB and take ~10-20sec to convert.

Using that  benchmark, if I process a 20,000 KB kml, the time will be 10 * 20 = 200 seconds = 3min.

At 1.4-2 min, your machine is processing kmls faster than mine.

Comment: Valid point. Occasionally we have 365 KMLs per one data query. A processing time of 1.4-2 minutes gives us a total script runtime of 8.5 hours (511 minutes) to 12.2 hours (730 minutes). Was hoping to reduce this drastically but our machines are what they are (GFE!). Thank you.